# Error al utilizar el vector de inicialización de criptografía IV

Tags: c#, encriptación

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.'

EL anterior error me sale cuando utilizo el vector de inicialización IV y no se que puede ser, estoy tratando de encriptar un archivo.

Utilizo el lenguaje d programación c# con elesquema de cifrado Rijndael.

EL anterior error me sale cuando utilizo el vector de inicialización IV y no se que puede ser, estoy tratando de encriptar un archivo.

Utilizo el lenguaje d programación c# con elesquema de cifrado Rijndael.

```
 using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Security.Cryptography;
        
        
        namespace Encriptado
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                private object file;
        
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
        
                byte[] encriptar(byte[] bytesAencriptar, byte[] clave)
                {
                    byte[] bytesEncriptados = null;
                    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //using (var aen = new RijndaelManaged())
                        using (RijndaelManaged? aen = new RijndaelManaged())
                        {
                            aen.KeySize = 256;
                            aen.BlockSize = 128;
        
        
                            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(clave, salt, 1000);
                            aen.Key = key.GetBytes(aen.KeySize / 8);
                            aen.IV = key.GetBytes(aen.KeySize / 8);
                            aen.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                            using (var crp = new CryptoStream(ms, aen.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                crp.Write(bytesAencriptar,0,bytesAencriptar.Length);
                                crp.Close();
                            }
                            bytesEncriptados = ms.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                    return bytesEncriptados;
                }
        
                private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        
        
                var file = new OpenFileDialog();
        
                if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var data = file.FileName;
                    byte[] archivoAencriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(data);
                    byte[] clave = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MICLAVE");
                    clave = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(clave);
                    byte[] archivoEncriptado = encriptar(archivoAencriptar, clave);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(data, archivoEncriptado);
                }
                }
        
                private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var file = new OpenFileDialog();
                    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        var data = file.FileName;
                        byte[] archivoAencriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(data);
                        byte[] clave = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MICLAVE");
                        clave = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(clave);
                        byte[] archivoEncriptado = encriptar(archivoAencriptar, clave);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(data, archivoEncriptado);
                    }
        
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: En vez de poner spam, podrías poner el error completo. El error completo. Completo. Todo el error. Una traza del error. Ve a [edit] la pregunta. Edita la pregunta. Edita. Mejora la pregunta. Mejórala. Hazla mejor. Ajústala a los lineamientos de Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El vector de inicialización puede ser cualquier cadena siempre y cuando cumpla con ser de longitud

```
algorithm.BlockSize / 8
```

Que en tu caso serían 16 bytes. `MICLAVE` no cumple con eso, así que encuentras ese error. Genera una cadena que sea de 16 bytes. `MICLAVEMICLAVE12` o lo que prefieras.